# Sample size and power analysis: Chi-square

Tags: chi-squared-test, sample-size, multiple-comparisons, effect-size

Can someone help with a sample size analysis question?

Study design:
I have a sample randomly assigned to answer 1 of 5 different questions that vary in difficulty (1 - Easy -> 5 - Hard). The question is true/false question (binomial).

I plan to conduct a chi-square test of independence to see if there's a relationship between question assigned and rate of correct response. I plan to do follow-up chi-square tests to answer my question: do people assigned more difficult questions have a lower rate of correct responses?

This would require comparing group 1 to 2,3,4,5 and then group 2 to 3,4,5 and so on.

My intention is to identify my sample size based on the smallest hypothesized effect. The logic being that I want to obtain a sample size that enables me to detect the smallest hypothesized effect.

I have pilot data to help me calculate effect sizes. Does it make sense for me to do all the comparisons between groups in my search for the smallest effect?